# Parameter in the src of the Facebook images

Tags: php, html, image, facebook, src

I looked at the src of a Facebook image and I wonder what the settings send after the (?)

> src="https://scontent-cdt1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/104880523_2540046292992044_6592610077254805518_n.jpg?_nc_cat=110&ccb=2&_nc_sid=8bfeb9&_nc_ohc=I0hK-Kd_7joAX89l9i5&_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.xx&oh=35064ecb3ae37454d579fbc012d6421d&oe=60214500"

If I remove the parameters I get an error message displayed in my browser "Bad URL timestamp".

> src="https://scontent-cdt1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/104880523_2540046292992044_6592610077254805518_n.jpg"

What are these parameters used for? Who exploits them PHP or the server?

Thanks for your help

Comment: It is data Facebook needs to show the image.

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion, Its necessary setting of Image URL by Facebook for reaching out Facebook's database to you.
**You can't remove these parameters**. If want to short URL then use online URL shorting websites.

Comment: i think op wanted to know what each of them means

Comment: I want to know which technology exploits these parameters, the PHP programming language or the server itself (Apache,Nginx...)